# lm and nls F test in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, nonlinear-regression, likelihood-ratio, f-test

I am trying to compare a linear model and other non linear models(Asymptotic, Logistic and Ricker) by means of an F test or a likelihood ratio test. I have tried anova(Linear, Logistic,Ricker, Asymptote) but this generates an error. Is there a way to do this in R?

I used the following models:

```
Linear<-lm(mean~age,Lmaxl)
Logistic<- nlsLM(mean ~ k/(1+((k- Bo)/Bo)*exp(-r*age)), 
    data=Lmaxl, start=list(k=50,Bo=20,r=0.1), 
    control=li‌st(maxiter=200),
    na.action="na.exclude")
Asymptote<-nlsLM(mean ~k+(Bo-)*exp(-r*age), 
    data=Lmaxl,
    start=list(k=50,Bo=20,r=0.1),
    control=list(maxit‌​er=200),
    na.action="na.exclude")
 Ricker<- nlsLM( mean~ Bo+(a*age)*exp(-b*age), 
    data=Lmaxl, 
    start=list(Bo=10, a=5, b=0.01),
    control=list(maxiter=200),
    na.action="na.exclude")
```

Comment: How did you estimate your non-linear models? Nonlinear least-squares? Are the models nested?

Comment: Hi Maarten, here are the models. 
Linear<-lm(mean~age,Lmaxl)***

Logistic<- nlsLM(mean ~ k/(1+((k-Bo)/Bo)*exp(-r*age)),data=Lmaxl,start=list(k=50,Bo=20,r=0.1),control=list(maxiter=200),na.action="na.exclude")***

Asymptote<-nlsLM(mean ~k+(Bo-k)*exp(-r*age),data=Lmaxl,start=list(k=50,Bo=20,r=0.1),control=list(maxiter=200),na.action="na.exclude")***

Ricker<- nlsLM( mean~ Bo+(a*age)*exp(-b*Closure.age), data=Lmaxl, start=list(Bo=10, a=5, b=0.01),control=list(maxiter=200),na.action="na.exclude")

Comment: If you seek help because of an error message you should not keep said error message top-secret.

Comment: That gives me the commands you used, but does not answer my questions. I could look it up, but that is the wrong way around. So again: did you use nonlinear least squares or maximum likelihood or generalized method of moments or ... to estimate these models? Are these models nested?

Comment: Hi Roland, this is the error message. Warning message:
In anova.lmlist(object, ...) :
  models with response ‘c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL")’ removed because response differs from model 1

Comment: The models are not nested. Essentially I am predicting tree biomass as a function of age using different models. I have evaluated the model that fits the data better using the AIC criterion and an approximation of R2. The models do not seem different, as a result I wanted to evaluate the goodness of fit using an F test or a likelihood ratio test... may be compute p values for the fit

Comment: F-tests and likelihood ratio tests require nested models.

Comment: I believe there's an underlying statistical issue that needs to be discussed here.

Comment: @Glen_b I thought this would be possible as the dependent and independent variables are similar, only the model paramters differ i.e parameters for the linear equation and those of the logistic,asymptotic and Ricker models

Comment: Please explain your underlying question in the question body. Are you trying to find the "best" model? How would you assess "best"? What is the research question your are trying to answer by the model comparison?